# Perl - take first 16 bytes from string

Tags: string, perl, byte, take

I have a string which contains `45f5f5ca1997b35bf09b8e0932b0d693967d0608a3c`

How can I take first 16 bytes of that string?

Comment: If your hex string represents some byte values (every **two chars** in a hex string make **one** byte value), where example : `45` is 1st byte, `F5` is 2nd byte and so on... Taking 16 letters with `substr($s, 0, 16)` only gives you 8 byte values (if hex string is converted to binary) or since each ASCII letter itself has own byte to represent the letter (eg: letter `A` is byte `41`) so your starting `45` makes letter `E` (in string format) or the value `69` (in binary format). Don't assume `4` and `5` are two separate bytes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are composed of elements called "characters" (which may or may not be bytes). To get a string that consists of the first 16 characters of another string, you can use the following:

```
 substr($s, 0, 16)
```

Comment: Still confused how he asked for **bytes** (from obviously a hex string) but the correct Answer was to "use substring" to extract ASCII **text**? I've tried to edit Asker's title so this Answer fits (for future readers).

Comment: @VC.One, You shouldn't surprised if you see it as ASCII text because "ASCII text" means "the bytes obtained when you encode text using ASCII".

Comment: Technically your answer is correct... For example a string of all the A to Z letters contains 26 bytes. So for first 16 bytes, just get the first 16 letters in string. The complication is that (it looks like) a hex string possibly returned by some (API?) request that could not provide bytearray and so returned byte array values in a text string. Example : A Jpeg begins with 2 bytes `FF D8`, so from string like `"FFD8"` doesn't **substring** for first 2 letters only give `"FF"` (or bytes `46 46`) ? This logic can't confirm JPG header as (int) 255 and 216, when the "FF" result is (int) 70 and 70

Comment: @VC.One, Oh I know the OP could have meant something else. There's no denying the OP could have meant something other than what they actually asked. So I answered the question actually asked, but I clearly stated what the answer does so the OP could judge if it's that's what they actually wanted. I also upvoted the answer that covered the answer the OP might have meant to ask, and I left an improved method of achieving the same result in a comment to it. I'm way ahead of you, dude.

Comment: _"I'm way ahead of you, dude"_ yes you are and your power is freaking me out (in a good way, haha). I'm not confused anymore. You literally answered _"take first 16 bytes **of that string**"_ and OP is actually satisfied with it.

Answer (score 2):

looks like you need hexadeximals convert to bytes.

```
my $hex = "45f5f5ca1997b35bf09b8e0932b0d693967d0608a3c";

my @bytes = map { hex } $hex =~ m/(..)/g;


use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\@bytes);

print join('', map { sprintf("%x", $_) } @bytes);
```

feel free to limit array size by 16 elements by yourself (`substr($hex, 0, 16*2)`).

Comment: Better: `my @bytes = unpack 'C*', pack 'H*', $hex;` (all) or `my @bytes = unpack 'C16', pack 'H32', $hex;` (first 16)